# Get the specified part of an hbitmap.

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, bitmap

There is an HBITMAP which can be displayed successfully. I want get a portion (specified by a rect) of the bitmap, so is the following code but the returned bitmap is always black. Is there something wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
HBITMAP GetSelectedBitmap(HBITMAP p_bitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height){

    HDC l_srcDc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    ::SelectObject(l_srcDc, p_bitmap);

    HDC l_dstDc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(l_srcDc);

    HBITMAP l_newBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(l_dstDc, width, height);
    HBITMAP l_oldBitmap = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(l_dstDc, l_newBitmap);
    ASSERT(0 != ::BitBlt(l_dstDc, 0, 0, width, height, l_srcDc, x, y, SRCCOPY));
    HBITMAP l_clippedBitmap = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(l_dstDc, l_oldBitmap);
    ::DeleteDC(l_srcDc);
    ::DeleteDC(l_dstDc);
    return l_clippedBitmap;}
```

Comment: Is the source bitmap a DDB or a DIB? Does `SelectObject()` return NULL when selecting the bitmap into the source HDC? You are also not saving and restoring the source HDC's original bitmap before destroying the HDC.

Comment: Placing the `BitBlt` inside an `ASSERT` macro will compile to a no-op in a Release Build.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause,  change

```
HBITMAP l_newBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(l_dstDc, width, height);
```

to

```
HBITMAP l_newBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(l_srcDc, width, height);
```

fix the issue. that means `CreateCompatibleBitmap` should use the source DC.

Comment: The issue is a different one: [`CreateCompatibleDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489.aspx) creates a memory DC, whose *"display surface is exactly one **monochrome** pixel wide and one monochrome pixel high."* Creating a compatible bitmap will create a **monochrome** bitmap. Your solution works, since you select an appropriate (color) bitmap into your `l_srcDC`, prior to calling `CreateCompatibleBitmap`.